# Populate the monthly date from quarterly date in Oracle

Tags: oracle, datetime, date-arithmetic

I have values in a FACT table as below:

```
As of Date  F_Type      Value
31-Mar-17   ABC Corp    1.0
30-Jun-17   ABC Corp    1.1
```

As of dates are quarter end dates, now i need to write a query to get result set as below:(Month end dates between the dates after the value is changed)

```
As of Date  F_Type      Value
31-Mar-17   ABC Corp    1.0
30-Apr-17   ABC Corp    1.0
31-May-17   ABC Corp    1.0
30-Jun-17   ABC Corp    1.1
```

How can i populate the 30-Apr-17 and 31-May-17 rows??

Code tried so far:

```
SELECT 
As_Of_Date,
F_Type,
Value,X.*
FROM FACT F INNER JOIN
(SELECT M_DATE,trunc(M_DATE+1,'Q')-1 AS QTR_DATE FROm
(Select TO_DATE('31-JAN-2017','DD-MON-YYYY') AS M_DATE from dual UNION ALL
Select TO_DATE('28-FEB-2017','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual UNION ALL
Select TO_DATE('31-MAR-2017','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual UNION ALL
Select TO_DATE('30-APR-2017','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual UNION ALL
Select TO_DATE('31-MAY-2017','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual UNION ALL
Select TO_DATE('30-JUN-2017','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual UNION ALL
Select TO_DATE('31-JUL-2017','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual UNION ALL
Select TO_DATE('31-AUG-2017','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual UNION ALL
Select TO_DATE('30-SEP-2017','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual UNION ALL
Select TO_DATE('31-OCT-2017','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual UNION ALL
Select TO_DATE('30-NOV-2017','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual UNION ALL
Select TO_DATE('31-DEC-2017','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual ) )X
ON F.As_Of_Date=X.QTR_DATE
```

This gives me something like below:

```
As of Date  F_Type      Value   M_Date   Qtr_Date
3/31/2017   ABC Corp    1.0   3/31/2017  3/31/2017
3/31/2017   ABC Corp    1.0   4/30/2017  3/31/2017
3/31/2017   ABC Corp    1.0   5/31/2017  3/31/2017
6/30/2017   ABC Corp    1.1   6/30/2017  6/30/2017
6/30/2017   ABC Corp    1.1   7/31/2017  6/30/2017
6/30/2017   ABC Corp    1.1   8/31/2017  6/30/2017
```

Is there a way to tune this query and output as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below query may work out for you, I tried with your table and checked the output.

```
 SELECT * FROM FACT
 UNION
 SELECT ADD_MONTHS(AS_OF_DATE,LVL.LVL2) DT,
          FACT.F_TYPE,
          FACT.VALUE
 FROM FACT,
       (SELECT LEVEL AS LVL2
         FROM DUAL
          CONNECT BY LEVEL<=2) LVL
         ,(SELECT  MAX(AS_OF_DATE) DT2 
          FROM FACT) FC2 
      WHERE ADD_MONTHS(AS_OF_DATE,LVL.LVL2)<=FC2.DT2
```

I have taken the below data set:

```
As of Date  F_Type      Value
31-Mar-17   ABC Corp    1.0
30-Jun-17   ABC Corp    1.1
30-Sep-17   ABC Corp    1.2
```

Added the Sep row to test authenticity of my query.

and I am getting output as:

```
As of Date  F_Type      Value
31-Mar-17   ABC Corp    1.0
30-Apr-17   ABC Corp    1.0
31-May-17   ABC Corp    1.0
30-Jun-17   ABC Corp    1.1
31-Jul-17   ABC Corp    1.1
30-Aug-17   ABC Corp    1.1
30-Sep-17   ABC Corp    1.2
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Probably you should use `last_day()` to ensure the generated dates are month ends, because 30rh is not the last day of July.

Comment: I didn't paste the result data set from my database, perhaps I edited it by hand, I shall correct the answer. Thank you @APC for letting me know. The question assumed data will be of month end, so I used add_months which makes the next date also month end.

Comment: Thanks @kratostoical

Comment: @kratostoical As per the description your solution works perfectly.However, i have encountered another problem here. The dates are not always quarter end dates. there can be a month end date as well (so the requirement changes completely). For instance if we add a row  like 8/31/2017 ABC Corp 1.3  in the fact table.The solution gives two rows for 8/31/2017 one with value 1.1 and another with value 1.3. But the correct business need is to have just one row with value 1.3
It should eliminate row 8/31/2017 with value 1.1 in the result set.

Comment: @Novice_Techie What is the primary key of the table ?

Comment: @kratostoical we can have a column called fact ID as PK